# small size picture problem

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator

I've got a problem in saving  a picture in a full size after capturing it using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent the picture become very small , its resolution is 27X44 I'm using 1.5 android emulator, this is the code and I will appreciate any help:

```
myImageButton02.setOnClickListener
(
    new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // create camera intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //Grant permission to the camera activity to write the photo.
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            //saving if there is EXTRA_OUTPUT
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File
            (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testExtra" + String.valueOf
            (System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")));
            // start the camera intent and return the image
            startActivityForResult(intent,1); 
        } 
    }
);
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // if Activity was canceled, display a Toast message
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"camera cancelled", 10000);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }

    // lets check if we are really dealing with a picture
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // get the picture
        Bitmap mPicture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        // save image to gallery
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mPicture, timestamp, timestamp);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Haya, please indent your code properly so it is readable

Comment: Great commenting, Haya. Your code is also easier to read now. I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you though, I hope someone is able to assist soon.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what you are doing:

- you specify a path where your just taken picture is stored with `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File        (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testExtra" + String.valueOf           (System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")));`
- when you access the picture you 'drag' the data out of the intent with `Bitmap mPicture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`

Obviously, you don't access the picture from its file. As far as I know Intents are not designed to carry a large amount of data since they are passed between e.g. Activities. What you should do is open the picture from the file created by the camera intent. Looks like that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
// Limit the filesize since 5MP pictures will kill you RAM  
bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 6;  
imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToPicture, bitmapOptions);
```

That should do the trick. It used to work for me this way but I am experiencing problems since 2.1 on several devices. Works (still) fine on Nexus One.
Take a look at [MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

Hope this helps.
Regards,
Steff