# How to get full resolution picture

Tags: android

Hello I created a android code to take picture, the code worked well but when I get a copy of picture the resolutions is very low. How can I get full resolution.
This is my code:

```
private void cameraIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.destinationUpload);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"img.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [small size picture problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410678/small-size-picture-problem)

Comment: How do you show the image on the imageView ? Can you share the code which you are using to convert the saved file to bitmap again ?

Also, sometimes, there are options in the device itself , where you can select resolution.If that setting is set to low resolution, then that could also lead to this problem. You can check that also. But if the problem persists in all the devices, it means the problem is in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have so much fun supporting all the different camera applications.

You're half way there. The docs say that

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT

```
intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.destinationUpload);
```

tells the camera app to save the image to the file at `destinationUpload`. Now you can read that file, or you can get a MediaStore URI to that file. The latter will work better for sharing.

Use

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            callback.result(uri);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried it, but don't worked. Could you give me a example?

Comment: That pretty much is the example. You should get a call to `onActivityResult` when a photo is taken. The you can expect a photo saved to `destinationUpload`.

Comment: I used this code, but dont solved the problem, works like my previous code, send a low resolution.

Comment: Are you still reading the "data" field? For me it was very inconsistent, so I only used the file specified for the image.